# Why is linux renaming directories when copying over network?

Tags: linux, samba, rsync

Running the command

```
sudo rsync -a -e ssh /home/blah user@server:/home/blah
```

rsync seems to be renaming directories (not sure if it is renaming files). For example, "M.I.A." is being converted to "MPTBTC~C". This also happens when copying over samba.

The target file system is ext4.

Update: This appears to only happen with directories that end with a period. A google search indicates this should only be a problem under windows, but I am syncing from linux (ext3) -> linux (ext4).

Comment: What version of rsync do you have and what does it claim it is doing when you use -vn?  Can you construct a new directory on the source system and a new target directory which reproduces the problem?  If so, please provide a script to create the example setup and rsync it.

Comment: Apparently, this is not strictly an rsync issue. Attempting to copy the directories over samba also results in the same problem.

Comment: Also, this does not happen when doing the rsync or copy locally.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `--iconv` parameter of `rsync` to rule out encoding issues. For example:

```
rsync -a -e ssh --iconv=utf8,iso88591 /home/blah user@server:/home/blah
```

This will force rsync to use UTF-8 for local filenames and ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) for remote filenames, "translating" as needed.

You can also try using the `convmv` utility (`apt-get install convmv` on Debian-based systems) to fix local encoding issues, although the filename you posted doesn't look like the kind of name `convmv` generally fixes.

Also, please post links to the findings you mention.